# How to compare arrays and remove duplicates in GAS?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, comparison

How to get this one to yield a list of the unique ID's after comparison?

[image]

It's giving me an empty list, although everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)  and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

If you want to check for values that are in `uniqueIDs1` but not in `uniqueIDs2`:

```js
let uniqueIDs1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let uniqueIDs2 = [1,3,4,6];
let unique_values = uniqueIDs1.filter(x => !uniqueIDs2.includes(x));
console.log(unique_values) // [ 2, 5 ]
```

If you want to check for values that are in `uniqueIDs1` but not in `uniqueIDs2` and in `uniqueIDs2` but not in `uniqueIDs1`:

```js
  let uniqueIDs1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
  let uniqueIDs2 = [1,3,4,6,10];
  let uv1 = uniqueIDs1.filter(x => !uniqueIDs2.includes(x));
  let uv2 = uniqueIDs2.filter(x => !uniqueIDs1.includes(x));
  let uv = uv1.concat(uv2);
  console.log(uv) // [ 2, 5, 10 ]
```

Comment: Not sure how includes works yet, but it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @AntonioSantos it checks if an element is included in an array of elements and if it does it returns `true` otherwise `false`. So it can be used in the `filter` function.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
function in1notin2() {
  let uniqueIDs1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  let uniqueIDs2 = [1, 3, 4, 6, 10];
  Logger.log(uniqueIDs1.filter(e=>{return !uniqueIDs2.includes(e)}));
}
```